# Excel VBA - Copy + Paste Based on Whether a Number is in Another Cell

Tags: excel, vba

In short, what I'm trying to do is have a button at the top of an excel spreadsheet with an assigned VBA macro that will copy an already set up hyperlink in, lets say Cell B2 and paste down from B3:B200 based on whether there is a number (could be any number from 1 to 10000) in a Cell in column A of the same row.

Edit:

Code will need to look something like below but I'm not very knowledgeable about VBA terms

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set Rng = ws.Range("A3:A200")

   For Each cell In Rng
        If IsNumeric(cell) = True Then
        Range ("B2").Copy
   "And now paste in adjacent cell in Row B if number in Row A is found" 

    Else "Do Nothing"

   "Repeat for all cells in range"
```

Hope that explains it a bit better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing when trying to get this to work?  What exactly is preventing you from setting this up as described?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm entirely new to writing VBA code so I don't even know where to begin. I have tried recording a macro which only gets me so far. It can copy and paste the hyperlink within a set range regardless of whether there is a number in the adjacent cell. The reason the code needs to recognise whether there is a number in the cell is because in between the grouped sections of items is text and formatting, which a recorded macro will just delete and replace with a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

I might try using something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Row As Integer
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Row = 3 To 200
  If IsNumeric(Cells(Row, "A")) Then
'And now paste in adjacent cell in Row B if number in Row A is found
    Range("B2").Copy Range("B" & Row)
  Else 'Do Nothing"
  End If
'Repeat for all cells in range"
Next Row

End Sub
```

I used row 200 because that was your example, adjust as needed.

Comment: Thank you! It was picking up on all of the empty cells too but after adding in a quick  "And isEmpty" function it all worked perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer so anyone in the future that has a similar issue can easily find it.